# How do I install Myst 4 Revelation on OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install Myst IV Revelation on OS X 10.6, but the installer keeps bombing out without ever doing anything. This software used to work on older versions of OS X. Does anybody have any ideas on how to do the install?

Comment: FYI, Mac OS hasn't "Bombed" since OS 9. Perhaps since OS 8.5...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomb_(symbol)

Comment: Gaming questions are outside the scope of SU. Try one of the sites listed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4

Comment: @random, this isn't a gaming question, it's a "Why is my software installer is crashing on my new OS?" question. Who cares if the contents of the installer is a game?

@Ryan, Is the "installer" a .pkg? If so, it's actually a folder with an "Archive.pax.gz" somewhere inside it. Unarchive that and you've got your files.

Otherwise it's probably a PowerPC-only binary. Default installs of Snow Leopard don't include Rosetta, which lets PowerPC apps run on Intel Macs. Use your Snow Leopard install DVD to install Rosetta and see if the installer runs.

Comment: More detail on the scope of games are out scope: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44631/game-installer-problems-on-su/44632#44632 @spi

Comment: Well, I answered my own question, after much work. Sadly, this will be lost to the sands of SU history.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a folder on your desktop called `myst4`
2. Inside this folder make two more folders, one called `Myst4_1` and one called `Myst4_2`
3. Insert disk 1 and open the terminal
4. Type `cd /Volumes/Myst4_1`
5. Type `cp -Rv * ~/Desktop/myst4/Myst4_1` - this will take a while
6. Type `cd /`
7. Eject disk 1 and insert disk 2
8. Type `cd /Volumes/Myst4_2`
9. Type `cp -Rv * ~/Desktop/myst4/Myst4_2` - this will take a while
10. Type `cd ~/Desktop/myst4/Myst4_1`
11. Type `unzip Macinstaller.jar`
12. Type `java run` - The installer will load
13. Accept all the defaults, keep clicking next
14. When prompted for disk 2, navigate to `Desktop/myst4/Myst4_2` and click open

The application is now installed. Not to run the game.

At the terminal
1. Type `cd /Ubisoft/MystIV`
2. Type `chmod -R 777 myst4.app`

Run the game by opening `Myst4` under the `Macintosh HD/Ubisoft/MystIV` directory.

Comment: Turns out the app is just not compatible with 10.6. It works fine in Windows 7 with Boot Camp. So much for Apple's legedary backwards compatibility.

Comment: The backwards incompatibility issue is related to the JVM, not Mac OS X.  It would make more sense to criticize an native app that wasn't backwards compatible.